# Maven if-else like behaviour

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module project  in maven, where other projects need to use the jars according to the environment.

We have like 4 enviroenments
1.Dev
2.UAT
3.QA 
4.PROD

There is a project which wants to use projectname-dev.jar for all three environments (i.e dev,uat,QA ) and projectname-prod.jar for PROD.

I did a google search for something like an if-else logic which I can use in maven profiles.

I can still create a new property for this specific project and change it to '-prod' when it goes into produciton, but thats an extra overhead that I do not want to add.

Are there any plugins I can use for this which will help me get the above work done without adding any kind of manual overhead to it.

Thanks

Comment: I would only run maven in development.  I would use maven to do a release and its that release I would use **unchanged** in UAT, QA and PROD. If there are configuration differences between environments I would maintain these separately.

Comment: The problem here would be that an organisation where there are three teams dedicated to development, uat and qa respectively, they would depend on one guy to create their builds. :)

Comment: I would have a continuous integration server e.g. hudson and have it that any one could perform the release (with instructions) The problem you have is that UAT and QA could build something almost but not exactly the same as DEV. And have something different again go into production.

Comment: I think @Peter's point is that there is only one build anyway.  The other teams shouldn't be creating builds, only using them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isn't it what [Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) are intended to do? You can define different property values in different profiles and then activate one of them when performing a build.

Comment: Id rather than creating a new profile, I would rather go with creating a new property, <env> and pass the property to maven when Im building it using -Denv='myenv'.This is how ideally environments and enrivonment specific builds are done in maven.

Comment: I disagree with you @Neeraj. axtavt is quite correct in recommending the use of profiles. In the profile you can specify as many properties as you like specific to that type of build. Much more flexible that defining each property on the command line

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but you shouldn't be building environment-specific artifacts. Contrary to popular opinion, this is a terrible misuse of Maven profiles. You should build one artifact that is suitable for any environment. The configuration of the artifact, which is external to the artifact, is what's specific to each environment.

Comment: Yes I completely agree with you.Rather than create 4 different profiles, the artifacts should have a configuration for each environment and that is exactly what im looking for here.

Comment: Then maybe we don't understand what you're asking for because it sounds like you're looking for a way to conditionally run a maven build targeted at different environments. More likely, you should do something like have maven build your artifact and use the [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to bundle the artifact along with multiple different environment configurations into a zip file.

Comment: It's very common to store db config into a war file. How would you configure this for dev, prod without having different artifacts for each build environment?